# Test if a dynamic variable is defined

Tags: forms, coldfusion

I have some input variables with a dynamic name into my form (UUID).
To avoid error I test if the variables are defined, but strangely the function IsDefined return me an error (when the field is not sent like a radio or check-box).

The HTML result in the form:

```
 Yes <input type="radio"id="content_BB66F151-CB09-1C8C-CCF53DE1A92652FC"
name="content_BB66F151-CB09-1C8C-CCF53DE1A92652FC" value="1">  
No <input type="radio" id="content_BB66F151-CB09-1C8C-CCF53DE1A92652FC"
name="content_BB66F151-CB09-1C8C-CCF53DE1A92652FC" value="0">
```

My CFM:

```
Yes <input type="radio" id="content_#qMD.MD_FIELD_ID#"
                        name="content_#qMD.MD_FIELD_ID#" value="1"> No <input type="radio" id="content_#qMD.MD_FIELD_ID#" name="content_#qMD.MD_FIELD_ID#" value="0">
```

My CFM test: I have a list of all MD_FIELD_ID and loop over them

```
<cfloop list="#attributes.lMetadataField#" index="MD_FIELD_ID" delimiters="," >
<cfif IsDefined("attributes.content_" & MD_FIELD_ID)>
</cfif>
```

Coldfusion return me this when the field is not in the submitted form:

> Parameter 1 of function IsDefined, which is now attributes.content_BB66F151-CB09-1C8C-CCF53DE1A92652FC, must be a syntactically valid variable name.

I have tried different syntaxes:

```
 IsDefined("attributes.content_#MD_FIELD_ID#") or
attributes["content_#MD_FIELD_ID#"]
```

but always the same error. If the field is in the submitted form, it works fine.

What is wrong in my code ?

Comment: Have you tried to rename the checkbox for testing purposes? Try StructKeyExists( attributes, "content_" & MD_FIELD_ID )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may not use hyphens (and various other characters like `:` or `#`) for struct key names (i.e. variables) when providing as argument to `isDefined`. Instead you can do:

`<cfif structKeyExists(attributes, "content_" & MD_FIELD_ID)>`

`structKeyExists` doesn't evaluate the expression and thus is not subject to the variable name parsing. However, due to that fact you cannot chain `structKeyExists` as conveniently.

Example:

```
isDefined("someStruct.parentKey.childKey")
```

translates to

```
structKeyExists(VARIABLES, "someStruct")
and structKeyExists(someStruct, "parentKey")
and structKeyExists(someStruct["parentKey"], "childKey")
```

Notice how you need to check existence for every single key in the chain. But it allows to use any character as key name.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, strucKeyExist do the job. I never thought that 'IsDefined' evaluate the expression, next time I will remove hyphens to replace by underscore to avoid this kind of problem.